# Need suggestion for Mutiple Windows application design

Tags: design, algorithms, wpf, mvvm

This was previously posted in StackOverflow, I just moved to here...

I am using VS2008, MVVM, WPF, Prism to make a mutiple window CRM Application.

I am using `MidWinow` in my `MainWindow`, I want

1. Any `ViewModel` would able to make request to `MainWindow` to create/add/close `MidChildWindow`, `ChildWindow`(from WPF Toolkit), `Window` (the Window type).
2. `ViewModel` can get the `DialogResult` from the `ChildWindow` its excutes.
3. `MainWindow` have control on all opened window types.

Here is my current approach:

I made `Dictionary` of each of the windows type and stores them into MainWindow class.

For 1, i.e in a `CustomerInformationView`, its `CustomerInformationViewModel` can execute `EditCommand` and use `EventAggregator` to tell MainWindow to open a new `ChildWindow`.

CustomerInformationViewModel:

```
CustomerEditView ceView = new CustomerEditView ();
CustomerEditViewModel ceViewModel = CustomerEditViewModel ();
ceView.DataContext = ceViewModel;
ChildWindow cWindow = new ChildWindow();
cWindow.Content = ceView;
MainWindow.EvntAggregator.GetEvent<NewWindowEvent>().Publish(new WindowEventArgs(ceViewModel.ViewModeGUID, cWindow ));
cWindow.Show();
```

Notice that all my `ViewModel` will generates a `Guid` for help identifies the `ChildWindow` from `MainWindow`'s dictionary. Since I will only be using 1 View 1 ViewModel for every Window.

For 2. In `CustomerInformationViewModel` I can get `DialogResult` by `OnClosing` event from `ChildWindow`, in `CustomerEditViewModel` can use `Guid` to tell MainWindow to close the ChildWindow.

Here is little question and problems:

Is it good idea to use Guid here? Or should I use HashKey from ChildWindow?

My `MainWindows` contains windows reference collections.  So whenever window close, it will get notifies to remove from the collection by `OnClosing` event.  But all the Windows itself doesn't know about its associated Guid, so when I remove it, I have to search for every KeyValuePair to compares...

I still kind of feel wrong associate ViewModel's Guid for ChildWindow, it would make more sense if ChildWindow has it own ID then ViewModel associate with it...

But most important, is there any better approach on this design? How can I improve this better?

Comment: Can you post the code from MainWindow?  Does it expose any public properties?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use a Guid or HashKey, you might find it easier to actually use a reference to the ChildWindow objects.

Also, in order to prevent memory leaks, while not having to worry about handling events, you can use a [weak reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) to the object so that the garbage collector can still reclaim the resources used by the object once it's no longer referenced anywhere.

I've found the folliwing .NET classes to be pretty handy when working with weak references:

- [WeakReference Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)
- [ConditionalWeakTable <TKey, TValue> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx)

Also, you can have each ChildWindow set it's own DataContext to the
appropriate ViewModel, either declaratively within the XAML, or in the code-behind.

---

**Edit**

Also, I thought I should clarify that if you use a collection of `WeakReference`'s to keep track of each window, you won't need to manually remove the reference from the collection whenever a window is closed. You can simply close your window (either from the code-behind, or anywhere else) & forget about it - the GC will still automatically deallocate the necessary resources.